# $A_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_AB\cong B_\mathfrak{q}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

**Question:** Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of rings which makes $B$ an $A$-algebra. Suppose $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal of $B$ and $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{p}$, then I want to know if we have $A_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_AB\cong B_\mathfrak{q}$ as rings?

I don't assume that $f$ is surjctive. I can consturct a map $A_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_AB\rightarrow B_\mathfrak{q}$ by $\frac{a}{s}\otimes b\rightarrow \frac{f(a)b}{f(s)}$. To prove the isomorphism, I want to construct the inverse map, but it seems to me there is no obvious map, since $f$ is not assumed to be surjcetive.

**Motivation:** This result is used to prove $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}/\mathfrak{m}y \, \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \simeq \mathcal{O}_{X_y, x}$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107636/prove-a-ring-isomorphism-of-stalks), User "nowhere dense" considered the map $B\xrightarrow{g} B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ in that question, and he got $(B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p})_\tilde{\mathfrak{q}}\cong
( A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_A B)\otimes_B B_\mathfrak{q}$. I don't know why this is true.

**Edit.** I don't think this question is just $S^{-1}A\otimes_A B\cong f(S)^{-1}B$, since we don't know $A-\mathfrak{p}$ doesn't map to $B-\mathfrak{q}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer is trivially no. Let $A=k$ be a field, $\mathfrak{p}=0$, $B=k[x]$, and $\mathfrak{q}=(x)$. You should edit your question to be more explicitly about the step you're confused about. Something like "I'm trying to understand why [thing you're confused about] is true and I had the following idea:...".

Comment: No. Consider the case when $A$ is a domain, $B = A[X]$, and $f$ is the inclusion map. Then take $\mathfrak{q} = \{0\} \subset B, \mathfrak{p} = \{0\} \subset A$. Then $A_{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathrm{Frac}(A)$, and $B_{\mathfrak{q}} = \mathrm{Frac}(A[X])$, but $A_{\mathfrak{p}} \otimes_{A} B \cong \mathrm{Frac}(A)[X]$, which is not the same as $\mathrm{Frac}(A[X])$.

Comment: @KReiser If my question is general wrong, does this hold for map $g: B\rightarrow B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$?  Namely, if $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal of the latter, then $B_{g^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})}\otimes_BB\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}\cong (B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p})_{\mathfrak{q}}$?

Comment: I can't really tell what your first sentence is asking - it would seem that in all the cases raised in the comments and answer so far, $p=0$, so $A_p/pA_p=A_p$ which puts you back in the scenario already addressed. I think you ought to ask a question starting from the beginning of your confusion, taking care to be as clear as you can about the context of the problem and what specifically you do not understand. (I would have recommended editing this one, but doing so would invalidate the answer which has been given, and that's frowned upon.)

Comment: @KReiser Thank you. I have accepted his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Suppose $A= \mathbb{C}, p=0$ and $B=\mathbb{C}[t], q=(t) $. The map $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}[t] $ is the inclusion. Note that $f^{-1}(q) = q \cap \mathbb{C} = 0$.

You have that $A_p = A$ because $\mathbb{C}$ is a field and everything beside zero is already invertible. Now
$$ A_p \otimes_A B = A \otimes_A B \simeq B$$

but
$$ B_q = \mathbb{C}[t]_{(t) }$$

is not isomorphic to $B$, because it is a local ring while $B$ has infinitely many maximal ideals.