# Localization of Kähler differential

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\phi: R\rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism, $\mathfrak{q}$ be a prime of $S$ and $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{p}$.

Then I'd like to know if $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes R_\mathfrak{p}\cong \Omega_{S_\mathfrak{q}/R_\mathfrak{p}}$ is correct. It seems that Akhil Mathew uses this in [proposition 1.8 on page 6](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/chetale.pdf), but I do not understand the proof:

> **Proposition 1.8.** Let $\phi: R\rightarrow S$ be a morphism of finite type. Then $\phi$ is unramified if and only if for every $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{R}$, we have $k(\mathfrak{p})\rightarrow S\otimes_R k(\mathfrak{p})$ is unramified.
>
> **Proof:** Suppose $k(\mathfrak{p})\rightarrow S\otimes_R k(\mathfrak{p})$ is unramified for all $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$. We then know that $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes_R k(\mathfrak{p})=\Omega_{S\otimes_R k(\mathfrak{p})/k(\mathfrak{p})}=0$ for all $\mathfrak{p}$. By localization, it follows that $\mathfrak{p}\Omega_{S_\mathfrak{q}/R_{\mathfrak{p}}}=\Omega_{S_{\mathfrak{q}}/R_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ for any $\mathfrak{q}\in\operatorname{S}$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$.

In fact, he deduces $\mathfrak{p}\Omega_{S_\mathfrak{q}/R_\mathfrak{p}}=\Omega_{S_\mathfrak{q}/R_\mathfrak{p}}$ from $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes \frac{R_\mathfrak{p}}{\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}}=0$. So I guess that he uses $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes R_\mathfrak{p}\cong \Omega_{S_\mathfrak{q}/R_\mathfrak{p}}$.

From my point of view, $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes R_\mathfrak{p}\cong\Omega_{S\otimes_RR_\mathfrak{p}/R_\mathfrak{p}}$, this is the tensor property of Kahler differential. But I don't think $S\otimes_RR_\mathfrak{p}\cong S_\mathfrak{q}$ holds, since this should require that $\phi(R-\mathfrak{p})=S-\mathfrak{q}$, but this is not true in general.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should put the relevant statement from the link in the question: this makes it easier for readers to see what you're talking about and protects against link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes_R R_p = \Omega_{S_p/R_p}$ which is not the same as $\Omega_{S_q/R_p}$ in general (any of the counterexamples at [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987099/a-mathfrakp-otimes-ab-cong-b-mathfrakq) will suffice here too). What is true is that $\Omega_{S_q/R_p}$ is the localization of $\Omega_{S_p/R_p}$ at the multiplicative set $S\setminus q$.

The way this is used in the proof is that $$\Omega_{S\otimes_R k(p)/k(p)}\cong \Omega_{S/R}\otimes_R (R_p/pR_p) \cong \Omega_{S/R} \otimes_R R_p \otimes_{R_p} R_p/pR_p \cong \Omega_{S_p/R_p} \otimes_{R_p} R_p/pR_p,$$ which is isomorphic to $\Omega_{S_p/R_p}/p\Omega_{S_p/R_p}$, as $M\otimes_R R/I\cong M/IM$ for any ring $R$, ideal $I$, and module $M$. So $p\Omega_{S_p/R_p}=\Omega_{S_p/R_p}$, and localizing at $S\setminus\mathfrak{q}$ and using the fact that $T^{-1}\Omega_{S/R}=\Omega_{T^{-1}S/R}$ we obtain the desired equality.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, you write the localization at $S-q$ of $p\Omega_{S_p/R_p}$ is $p\Omega_{S_q/R_p}$. Considering the known conditions, I guess you implicitly use the following fact: If $M$ is a module over a local ring $(A,p)$, and $q$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then $(pM)_q=pM_q$, where the localization is taken at $A-q$. Is this right?

Comment: Ok, this seems to be obvious...